# Sum of last value from users

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table in my postgresql database:

```
purchase

userid |    date    | price
---------------------------
     1 | 2016-01-06 |    10
     1 | 2016-01-05 |     5
     2 | 2016-01-06 |    12
     2 | 2016-01-05 |    15
```

I want the sum of the last purchase price of all users. For user 1 the last purchase is on 2016-01-06 and the price is 10. For user 2 the last purchase is on 2016-01-06 and the price is 12. So the result of the SQL query should by `22`.

How can I do that in SQL ?

Comment: Can user have more than one purchase per day?

Comment: Yes I can but normaly I also have time in date column. So it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All proposed solutions are good and work but as my table contains millions of records I had to find the more efficient way to do what I want. And it seems that the better way is to use the foreign key between the tables `purchase` and `user` (which I didn't mention in my question, my apologies) which is `purchase.user -> user.id`. Knowing this I can do the following request:

```
select sum(t.price) from (
    select (select price from purchase p where p.userid = u.id order by date desc limit 1) as price 
    from user u
) t;
```

**EDIT**

To answer to @a_horse_with_no_name here is `explain analyse verbose` for his and my solutions:
His solution:

```
Aggregate  (cost=64032401.30..64032401.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=566101.129..566101.129 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: sum(purchase.price)
    ->  Unique  (cost=62532271.89..64032271.89 rows=10353 width=16) (actual time=453849.494..566087.948 rows=12000 loops=1)
          Output: purchase.userid, purchase.price, purchase.date
          ->  Sort  (cost=62532271.89..63282271.89 rows=300000000 width=16) (actual time=453849.492..553060.789 rows=300000000 loops=1)
                Output: purchase.userid, purchase.price, purchase.date
                Sort Key: purchase.userid, purchase.date
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7620904kB
                ->  Seq Scan on public.purchase  (cost=0.00..4910829.00 rows=300000000 width=16) (actual time=0.457..278058.430 rows=300000000 loops=1)
                      Output: purchase.userid, purchase.price, purchase.date
Planning time: 0.076 ms
Execution time: 566433.215 ms
```

My solution:

```
Aggregate  (cost=28366.33..28366.34 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=53914.690..53914.690 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: sum((SubPlan 1))
    ->  Seq Scan on public.user2 u  (cost=0.00..185.00 rows=12000 width=4) (actual time=0.021..3.816 rows=12000 loops=1)
          Output: u.id, u.name
    SubPlan 1
      ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..2.35 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=4.491..4.491 rows=1 loops=12000)
            Output: p.price, p.date
            ->  Index Scan Backward using purchase_user_date on public.purchase p  (cost=0.57..51389.67 rows=28977 width=12) (actual time=4.490..4.490 rows=1 loops=12000)
                  Output: p.price, p.date
                  Index Cond: (p.userid = u.id)
Planning time: 0.115 ms
Execution time: 53914.730 ms
```

My table contains 300 million of records.
I don't know if it's relevant but I also have an index on `purchase (userid, date)`.

Comment: I am surprised that this performs better than the `distinct on()` solution. Would be interesting to see the execution plans (`explain (analzye, verbose)`) for both

Answer (score 4):

You can use windowed functions to get rank number and then use normal aggregation with `SUM`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY "date" DESC) AS r
   FROM purchase
)
SELECT SUM(price) AS total
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f29f/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that this solution calculates ties. To get only one purchase per user you need a column that is distinct per group (like `datetime`). But still it is possibility to get ties.

**EDIT:**

Handling ties:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase(
   userid INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,date   timestamp  NOT NULL
  ,price  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO purchase(userid,date,price) VALUES 
(1, timestamp'2016-01-06 12:00:00',10),
(1,timestamp'2016-01-05',5),
(2,timestamp'2016-01-06 13:00:00',12),
(2,timestamp'2016-01-05',15),
(2,timestamp'2016-01-06 13:00:00',1000)'
```

Note the difference `RANK()` vs `ROW_NUMBER`:

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_RANK`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d5c8/1/0)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_ROW_NUMBER`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d5c8/2/0)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_ROW_NUMBER_2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a7b9a/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ RANK() ║ ROW_NUMBER() ║ ROW_NUMBER() ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║   1022 ║           22 ║         1010 ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Without `UNIQUE` index on `userid/date` there is always possibility(probably small) for tie. Any solutions that is based on `ORDER BY` have to work on stable manner.

Comment: @cheb1k4 Do you have `userid/date` PK/UNIQUE? If not read my addendum

Comment: You are so right. Thank you for this enlightenment.

Answer (score 3):

To get the "latest" price you can use `distinct on ()` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (userid) userid, date, price
from the_table
order by userid, date desc
```

Now you only need to sum up all prices returned by the above statement:

```
select sum(price)
from (
   select distinct on (userid) userid, price
   from the_table
   order by userid, date desc
) t;
```

Comment: @lad2025: your solution would include ties as well. You would need to change your query to use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` to get exactly one purchase per userid

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used `rank()` because I wanted to calculate ties. With `ROW_NUMBER` there will be some sort of non-deterministic. Why to choose one over another without explicit column to get stable sort?

Comment: @lad2025: cheb1k4 mentioned that the column `date` is actually a `timestamp` (so much for good naming conventions...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So can we  assume that timestamp is always distinct per group and we get stable sort?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LATERAL join in this case:

```
SELECT sum(price) 
FROM (
  select distinct userid FROM purchase
) u, 
LATERAL (
  SELECT price FROM purchase p
  WHERE p.userid = u.userid
  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
) x
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5569b/5

Comment: Another working solution. Thank you. Now I have to test which one is faster :)

Comment: You can create a multicolumn index on ( userid, date DESC) columns to speed up these queries

Comment: Compare:  [Demo1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d5c8/3/0) vs [Demo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a7b9a/2/0). If userid/date is not unique you can't get **stable sort**.

Comment: @lad2025 you are absolutely right, thank you for pointing that.